# How to resolve empty task getting added to a react to-do app?

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react.js and I made a simple to-do app using react.js.
When the Enter key or the '+' button is pressed, the task gets added.
But, when I press enter key or '+' icon without any text a blank task gets added :

[image: to-do screenshot]

Here's my code :

```js
function Body() {
  const [toDos,setToDos] = useState([])
  const [toDo,setToDo] = useState('')
  const handleKeyPress = (event) => {
    if(event.key === 'Enter'){
      setToDos([...toDos,{id:Date.now() ,text: toDo, status: false}])
      setToDo("");
    }
  }
  const addTask = ()=>{
    setToDos([...toDos,{id:Date.now() ,text: toDo, status: false}])
      setToDo("");
  }
  const deleteTodo = idToDelete => setToDos(currentTodos => currentTodos.filter(toDo => toDo.id !== idToDelete))
    return (
        <div className="bodyoftodo"> 
          <div className="input">
            <input value={toDo} onChange={(e)=>setToDo(e.target.value)} type="text" placeholder="️ Add item..." onKeyPress={handleKeyPress} />
            <i onClick={addTask} className="fas fa-plus" ></i>
          </div>
          <div className="todos">
            {toDos.map((obj)=>{
             return(
              <div className="todo">
                <div className="left">
                  <input onChange={(e)=>{
                    console.log(e.target.checked);
                    console.log(obj);
                    setToDos(toDos.filter(obj2=>{
                      if(obj2.id===obj.id){
                        obj2.status=e.target.checked
                      }
                      return obj2
                    }))
                  }} value={obj.status} type="checkbox" name="" id="" />
                    <p className='todoName' >{obj.text}</p>
                </div>
              
                <div className="right">
                  <i onClick ={() => deleteTodo(obj.id)} className="fas fa-trash"></i>
                </div>
              </div>)
            }) }
```

I don't need to get an empty task. How do I resolve this?

Comment: just put `required` attribute in your input field and you can also check empty string before saving the new to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you have code duplication so I recommend you not to do it and just call `addTask`.

Secondly you can just check if the todo text is empty and if so - don't add the task `if(toDo === "") return;`:

```
const handleKeyPress = (event) => {
  if (event.key === 'Enter') {
    addTask();
  }
};

const addTask = () => {
  if(toDo === "") return;
  setToDos([...toDos, {id: Date.now(), text: toDo, status: false}]);
  setToDo("");
}
```